# how can i assign a closure class with a closure property

Tags: groovy, constructor, variable-assignment

I have a class something like this

```
class SomeClass () {
    Closure instClos

    SomeClass (Closure clos) { instClos = clos}  //constructor

    def call() {instClos()}
}
```

what i'd like to be able to do is do implicit Class constructor like this

```
 SomeClass myInst = {println "hello there}
 myInst()
```

but that doesn't work and throws cast exception.  you can make this work by writing [] round the closure to call the constructor.  but its not pretty

```
SomeClass myInst = [{println "hello there}]  // or myInst = new ({println "hello there}
myInst()
```

is there a nice way to create the object through assignment and have that closure stored automatically on the created class instance?

feel i'm missing some groovy syntax  here that would sort this  (PS i'd prefer not having to extend Closure if i can avoid that )

based on the input provided so far i provided an extended script to show the various options.  I tried to add an asType closure to Closure and try and call {...} as SomeClass - but if i tried that the asType is never called so groovy must be using another mechanism when you try a coercion

```
class SomeClass {
    Closure instClos

    SomeClass (Closure clos) {
        println "\tSomeClass constructor: Will constructor called"
        instClos = clos
    }

    def call() {
        println "\tSomeClass.call: calling closure "
        return (instClos() + "!")
    }

    SomeClass asType (Closure clos) {
        new SomeClass (instClos: clos)
    }
}

//this will call the map constructor - needs to be explicitly provided
SomeClass me = [{println "map style construction"; "echo"}]
assert me() == "echo!"

//use new to get class instance with constructor
me = new SomeClass ({println "new SomeClass () construction"; "echo"})
assert me() == "echo!"

//using layered closure approach - doesnt read well though
def someClos = {new SomeClass(it)}
def c = someClos {println "trying layered closure ";"echo"}
assert c() == "echo!"

//extending the Closure class to add a method
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
Closure.metaClass.some =  {
    if (it ==  SomeClass) {
        new SomeClass (delegate)
    }
}

//this will call .some() on closure
me = {println "hello will using .some() "; "echo"}.some ( SomeClass)
assert me() == "echo!"
```

Comment: What is the benefit of wrapping the closure with your own type? That is, why not just `def myInst = { println 'hello there' }; myInst()`?

Comment: i have other properties and functions in my wrapper class, above and beyond the closure i want to call.  i override the call() function on my wrapper to invoke the contained closure property.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anyway to auto-coerce a closure. Even though groovy has [closure coercion](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/groovy-goodness-implicit-closure.html), it works by changing the closure's type, but it's still a closure, and is not layered. Some ideas:

#### 1. Constructor

```
class SomeClass {
    Closure instClos
    SomeClass (Closure clos) { instClos = clos}  //constructor
    def call() {instClos() + "!"}
}

def c = new SomeClass( { "echo" } )

assert c() == "echo!"
```

#### 2. Map constructor

```
class SomeClass {
    Closure instClos
    def call() {instClos() + "!"}
}

SomeClass c = [instClos: { "echo" }]

assert c() == "echo!"
```

#### 3. Closure metaprogramming

(Needs [`enableGlobally()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543018/add-method-to-closure))

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()

Closure.metaClass.some = { new SomeClass(delegate) }

def c = { "echo" }.some()

assert c() == "echo!"
```

#### 4. Another closure layering

```
class SomeClass {
    Closure instClos
    SomeClass (Closure clos) { instClos = clos}  //constructor
    def call() {instClos() + "!"}
}

def some = { new SomeClass(it) }
def c = some { "echo" }
assert c() == "echo!"
```

#### 5. Override Closure's `asType`

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()

def asType = Closure.metaClass.asType
Closure.metaClass.asType = { Class c -> 
    (c == SomeClass) ? new SomeClass(delegate) : asType(c)
}

def c = { "echo" } as SomeClass

assert c() == "echo!"
```

Comment: thanks for this update - but i don't think these achieve the elegance i was hoping for.  i've expanded my sample as attached.  but the reason your last example didnt work was because your [{println "echo"}] initialiser will be a void return, the example below works as return "echo" from the closure

Comment: there is another unpleasent hack - i can declare an abstract AbsSomeClass with an abstract method like 'abstract Closure getClos().  You can then do a nasty closure coercion such as def myAbs = { return {..closure here..} }  assignment then use that ref myAbs.clos() to invoke the doubly embedded user closure  - but it aint pretty

Comment: i think i'm stimmied - what I want is to be able to overload the assignment operator  within groovy so i can control the RHS and convert it to the correct class type for the LHS.   i dont think that's a language feature yet by the looks of things

Comment: I think so too. It reminds me of [Scala implicit conversion](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions). I wonder if a [Groovy extension module](https://dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-adding-extra) could help someway?

Comment: um not sure i tried to add the asType to the closure metaclass and it wasnt called - so i think thenk they already have special handling for closure coercion and it kicks in before it get to my extension.  however i could give that a go and see what happens - thing is you dont want to break normal closure coercion for interfaces/sam types as then would be worse than what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: tried excplicit coercion like, x =  (SomeClass) {..}, and added asType to metaclass and my asType isnt called.  intercepted by other handling first

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough flexibility in your design you TRULY only need one method, `SomeClass.call()`, then you could specify it as an interface instead:

```
interface SomeClass {
    def call()
}
```

Groovy long ago anticipated the case that Java 8 formalizes with the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation. If you assign a Groovy Closure to variable or formal parameter of interface type, where the interface has only one method (like `SomeClass` as defined above), the Groovy compiler will coerce the closure into an instance of that interface. So, given the interface declaration above, the following code:

```
SomeClass myInst = { println "hello there" }
myInst()
```

prints "hello there".